# How to have same space between elements in list?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add the same space between li elements but I dont know how. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance

```css
  .container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10 ;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  
  #ul_top {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    list-style-type:none;
  }

  li:not(:first-child) {
    padding-right: 50px;
    color:red;
  }

  .title {
    padding-top: 80px;
  }

  .horizontal-line {
    width: 490px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left:10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
    position: relative;
    top:-20;

  }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
    <ul id ="ul_top">
      <li>text1</li>
      <li>text2</li>
      <li>text3</li>
      <li>text4</li>
      <li>text5</li>
      <li>text6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I want the same space distance between each li element and the last element (text6) to be move to the right a little bit so it lines up with the above horizontal line.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between/space-around`.

Also, a `ul` has a default padding, so just override it with `padding: 0`.

And I removed the `padding-right` for the `:not(:first-child)`

You can adjust the width of horizontal-line and the flexbox to be the same, and when you use space between you will have the line and text align together.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#ul_top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  color: red;
}

.title {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.horizontal-line {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
  position: relative;
  top: -20;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
  <ul id="ul_top">
    <li>text1</li>
    <li>text2</li>
    <li>text3</li>
    <li>text4</li>
    <li>text5</li>
    <li>text6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#ul_top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  color: red;
}

.title {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.horizontal-line {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
  position: relative;
  top: -20;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
  <ul id="ul_top">
    <li>text1</li>
    <li>text2</li>
    <li>text3</li>
    <li>text4</li>
    <li>text5</li>
    <li>text6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```